# Find a subspace such that $P=[\text{proj}_V]_A^A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose $P\subset M_n(\Bbb R^n)$ satisfies $P=P^T,P^2=P$ .
>   Show that there exists a subspace $V$ of $\Bbb R^n$ such that $P=[\text{proj}_V]_A^A$ where $A$ represents the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$
>   where the basis is taken to be the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$.

**My try**:

Since $P^2=P$ so any vector $v\in \Bbb R^n$ can be uniquely represented as

$v=v-Pv+Pv$ where $v-Pv\in \ker P$ and $Pv\in \text{Image }P$

Also $P$ is identity on $Image(P)$.

But I dont understand how can I construct the set $V$ such that $P=[\text{proj}_V]_A^A$
.

Can someone please help??

Comment: The set $V$ will be the eigenspace of $P$ corresponding to $\lambda = 1$, or equivalently, the columnspace of $P$. Answering the full question heavily depends on the specific definition of $\operatorname{proj}_V$ that you use. How is $\operatorname{proj}_V$ defined in your notes?

Comment: @Math_Freak are you sure that it is $M_{n}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and not $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$?